# How do I identify what addon a UI element belongs to?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

On my druid, when he gets clearcasting a massive white cooldown bar appears in the centre of the screen.  I looks like a Quartz bar, but unlocking Quartz doesn't reveal it and I've changed every Quartz option with no result.

I seem to recall there is a command or option that allows you to hover over UI elements and it tells you in a tooltip what their layer(?) is called (which includes which addon it belongs to).  Can anyone remind me what this is?

Alternatively, if anyone knows what addon the clearcasting bar might belong to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
/framestack
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late response, haven't played my druid in a week :P

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know, I found the dreaded addon that does this horrible action of placing dot timer bars right in front of your character. The addon is CLASSTIMER.

https://mods.curse.com/addons/wow/classtimer

This is a huge flaw in the UI design because it takes FOREVER to find this addon, even with /framestack or /fstack.

And yes, even in 2017 the addon has the SAME BEHAVIOUR. :S

Solution: *delete addon*

Comment: Thanks, I haven't played WoW in several years, but it's good that someone finally answered the second part of my question :)

Comment: See, kids, this is why necro-ing isn't bad per se.